# negative integers in binary

Tags: language-agnostic, signed, integer

```
 5 (decimal) in binary  00000101
-5 (two's complement) in binary 11111011
```

but 11111011  is  also 251 (decimal)!

How  does computer discern one from another??
How does it know whether it's -5 or 251??

it's THE SAME 11111011

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The computer actually doesn't care which is which; only programs do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signed bytes have a maximum of `127`.

Unsigned bytes cannot be negative.

The compiler knows whether the variable holding that value is of signed or unsigend type, and treats it appropriately.

Comment: how will exactly compiler convert signed 8-bit int a= -7  into binary?? will it generate 8-bit value or 32-bit (on 32-bit systems) with 24 zeros??

Comment: It will fill as large a space as it needs. But there will only be two 0s.

Answer (score 0):

If your program chooses to treat the byte as signed, the run-time system decides whether the byte is to be considered positive or negative according to the high-order bit. A 1 in that high-order bit (bit 7, counting from the low-order bit 0) means the number is negative; a 0 in that bit position means the number is positive. So, in the case of 11111011, bit 7 is set to 1 and the number is treated, accordingly, as negative.

Because the sign bit takes up one bit position, the absolute magnitude of the number can range from 0 to 127, as was said before.

If your program chooses to treat the byte as unsigned, on the other hand, what would have been the sign bit is included in the magnitude, which can then range from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

Two's complement is designed to allow signed numbers to be added/substracted to one another in the same way unsigned numbers are. So there are only two cases where the signed-ness of numbers affect the computer at low level.

1. when there are overflows
2. when you are performing operations on mixed: one signed, one unsigned

Different processors take different tacks for this. WRT orverflows, the MIPS RISC architecture, for example, deals with overflows using traps. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS_I_instruction_formats

To the best of my knowledge, mixing signed and unsigned needs to avoided at a program level.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "how does the program know how to interpret the value" - in general it's because you've told the compiler the "type" of the variable you assigned the value to. The program doesn't actually care if **00000101** as "5 decimal", it just has an unsigned integer with value **00000101** that it can perform operations legal for unsigned integers upon, and will behave in a given manner if you try to compare with or cast to a different "type" of variable.

At the end of the day everything in programming comes down to binary - all data (strings, numbers, images, sounds etc etc) and the compiled code just ends up as a large binary blob.